# Linq GroupBy not projecting all properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<>` of location reviews and the GroupBy I have written accurately groups them. However it will only allow two items to be projected and I can't find (googling) how to project the other properties.

In looking at the GroupBy definition I'm not even sure it's the correct extension method to use for my desired outcome but I can't find any alternatives.

My ungrouped collection is a `List<T>` I'm just using json notation to convey the structure.

```
userLocationReviews {
   userReview[0] {
    BusinessId="1234",
    BusinessName="Wonka Chocolate",
    LocationId = "443456",
    CityName="MyTown",
    RatingVale=5
   }
   userReview[1] {...}
   userReview[2] {...}
   ...
   userReview[100] {...}
}
```

I wrote this GroupBy and it is correct.

```
var groupedReviewedLocations = userLocationReviews.UserReviews.GroupBy(
    p => p.LocationId,
    p => p.RatingValue,
    (locId, rating) => new {LocationId = locId, Ratings = rating.ToList() });
```

Again this is a List just using json to show structure instead of a screen snippet.

```
groupedReviewLocations {
   Non-Public Members {...},
   ResultsView {
    [0]{
      LocationId: "1234",
      Ratings: {
        0:3,
        1:5,
        2:1,
        3:5
      }
    },
    [1]{...},
    .....
    [15]{...}
   }
}
```

However as mentioned above how do I get the other properties into the projection?

```
groupedReviewLocations {
   Non-Public Members {...},
   ResultsView {
    [0]{
      LocationId: "1234",
      Ratings: {},
      BusinessName: "Wonka Chocolate",
      CityName: "MyTown"
    },
    [1]{...},
    .....
    [15]{...}
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the

```
p => p.RatingValue,
```

line entirely

The group by is done by LocationId but by using this particular overload of GroupBy:

```
GroupBy(
  key-chooser,
  value-chooser,
  (Key, Values) list-processor
)
```

you're specifying which property you want in the output list in the second argument (value chooser).

If you instead use this overload:

```
GroupBy(
  key-chooser,
  (Key, Values) list-processor
)
```

The value is automatically determined to be the entire input object. You could also change the `p => p.RatingValue,` so it's just `p => p,` for the same effect (if that helps you understand what's going on)

---

It would make sense to change the `(locId, rating)` to `(locId, reviewedLocations)` as the second argument to that lambda will now be the list of location objects that share a key, rather than just a list of ratings. Also, because the second argument (you called it `rating`, I called it `reviewedLocations`) is a collection/multiple things it makes sense to give it a plural name